# Using BXmlLib.Format not recognized

Tags: c#

I'm trying to work on a program written in C# and at the start of the file it uses:

```
using BXmlLib.Format;
```

And then the `BXmlDocument` type is used by a few variables.

Can anyone please tell me how I can download this library or extension?

Comment: Try this: [https://github.com/search?q=BXmlLib](https://github.com/search?q=BXmlLib)

Comment: thanks for ur help i already serached google it had nothing but on github i got the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

stuartd:

> Try this: https://github.com/search?q=BXmlLib

hannan honey:

> thanks for your help... on github I got the dependencies.